# How to fix the LinearLayout as listview item

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, listview, xamarin

This is first time I post a android question here. Let me know if I did something wrong.

I have a listview and I am using this code as my listview item in my android project (xamarin, c#)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              a:layout_width="match_parent"
              a:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:adjustViewBounds="true"
        a:id="@+id/imgRecipeView" />
    <TextView
        a:id="@+id/recipeTitle"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="True" a:layout_below="@id/imgRecipeView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I want this imageview to take full width and height of it's own. Next currently my textview show on the image. I want to show them after the image (image on top, text on bottom, currently it's overlpapping).

I tried with linearlayout and relativelayout and it doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: What aspect of `LinearLayout` doesn't work for you

Comment: @zcui93 I want this imageview to have full width as the screen.

Comment: What's your layout's parent width? Full width?

Comment: yes, width of available screen (didn't applied anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this use **`LinearLayout`** with `orientation="vertical"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="match_parent"
    a:orientation="vertical"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:adjustViewBounds="true"
        a:scaleType="fitXY"
        a:id="@+id/imgRecipeView" />
    <TextView
        a:id="@+id/recipeTitle"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Hello @Prem, Is there any easy way I can just write and test my code. I means Visual studio xamarin take too much time and compile and see a little change.

Comment: I want to scale the image to the screen size. your code working fine except this.

Comment: did you try `match_parent` hight @Adrian

Comment: @Adrian happy to help you

Comment: Done! Prem, Is there anyway to just write and see changes, Like I does in html, just write and refresh browser

Comment: @Adrian didn't get u my friend

Comment: @Adrian Mobile app is written in compiled language, so unlike HTML, you can just reload to see the change. XAML is compiled down to .NET code to be executed on device. However, I believe Visual Studio should have some sort of `Forms Previewer` to let you visualize *roughly* what you will see on screen.